# Vue.js Active Menu color does not disable when page is changed

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, nuxt.js

My site is https://www.askarya.ir/en and I would like to have the ability to only have the active page navbar li colored red.

```
 <div class="navigation-items">
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li class="nav-item"><nuxt-link to="/en" class="nav-link">Home</nuxt-link></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><nuxt-link to="/en/about" class="nav-link">About Us</nuxt-link></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><nuxt-link to="/en/courses" class="nav-link">Courses</nuxt-link></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><nuxt-link to="/en/meetups" class="nav-link">Meetups</nuxt-link></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><nuxt-link to="/en/contact" class="nav-link">Contact Us</nuxt-link></li>           
    </ul>
  </div>
```

and the corresponding CSS

```
.nav-item a:hover,
.nav-item a:active,
.nav-item a.nuxt-link-active {
  color: red;
}
```

At the moment, the home page nav item is always illuminated even when on a different page, how can I only have the active page nav item illuminated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **exact** to your router link. This should solve your problem

```
<li class="nav-item"><nuxt-link to="/en" exact class="nav-link">Home</nuxt-link></li>
```

You find all attributes you can use for `<nuxt-link>` here: https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html

Comment: i have same question but how do i put class active in tag li ? i had question in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54029794/remove-class-nuxt-link-exact-active-or-giving-style-css-on-it?noredirect=1#comment94925385_54029794